# PHP 5.6 MySQLi turn off peer certificate cn validation

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, php-5.6

I am using PHP 5.6, MySQLi and SSL to connect to a database. However, I receive the error:

> Peer certificate CN=`hostname' did not match expected CN=`hostname'

Is there a way to turn off this check when using `mysqli::real_connect()`? I understand this makes man-in-the middle accounts easier.

Comment: I see there are plenty of other related questions [e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997493/ssl-cn-validation-with-self-signed-certificates) regarding validating certifications, however, I have not been able to determine how their suggestions can be used with MySQLi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options as I don't think there is a way of doing it directly within PHP (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68344)

1. Add the host's certificate to your 'trusted' certificates in your SSL library (most likely OpenSSL)
2. Compile PHP and disable/fix whatever code that does the host verification
3. Use stunnel to tunnel a local (non-SSL) connection to the remote MySQL SSL port